# How do I catch a git branch up to master when it is both ahead and behind?

Tags: git, bitbucket, branching-and-merging

I've created a branch called `shift-development` from `master` and did some work in the branch, putting it ahead of `master` by 40+ commits. I also made a small change to `master`, putting `shift-development` behind `master` by 1 commit. How do I catch `shift-development` up to `master`? i.e. bring the changes from the 1 commit to `master` into `shift-development`?

Comment: merge `shift-developement` into `master` and eventually solve merge conflicts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two options, you can [merge](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge) `master` to `shift-development` by calling the following command when being on `shift-development`:

```
git merge master
```

or alternatively, you can [rebase](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase) onto `master` by calling this command (assuming you are on `shift-development`):

```
git rebase master
```

The latter will not create a merge commit and the history will look like the brach has never got outdated.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, `git merge master` was what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are on the `shift-development` branch and do

```
git merge master
```